# Why can't I access this variable from the state VUEX 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex4

I of course tried it with out the state.groupCrud.group and still no go. Is my syntax correct. I am using vuejs3 i will provide some screenshots of the object.

This is the State Object:

```
const state = () => ({
  group: {}, //This is the one i am trying to access.
  groups: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  success: false,
});
```

I am getting the data from api like this:

```
  async getGroup({ commit }, id) {
    try {
      await commit('axiosSingleDataBegin');
      const query = await DataService.get(`/groups/unique/${id}`);
      await commit('axiosSingleDataSuccess', query.data.data.group);
    } catch (err) {
      await commit('axiosSingleDataErr', err);
    }
  },
```

And I am setting it to the state like this:

```
axiosSingleDataSuccess(state, data) {
    state.loading = false;
    state.group = data;
  },
```

This is how i am using the state

```
 setup() {
    const { state, dispatch } = useStore();
    const group = state.groupCrud.group;
    const { params } = useRoute();

    onMounted(() => {
      dispatch('getGroup', params.id);
      console.log(group); //doesnt work
    });

    // ...
  },
```

[This is the `console.log(state.groupCrud);` Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYjz4.png)

[This is the `console.log(state.groupCrud.group)` Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhl4l.png)

I am getting a empty Proxy object when i try to use the state.groupCrud.group although the object is not empty